# Overleaf compile Error

Tags: errors, overleaf

I'm new with LaTeX and Overleaf and I'm getting a compile error without error message while compiling the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[clearempty]{titlesec}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{ics}{ICS}{Ice Cream Sandwich}


\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-icomp,    
firstinits=true,
isbn=false,                
pagetracker=true,          
maxbibnames=50,            
maxcitenames=2,            
autocite=inline,           
block=space,               
backref=true,              
backrefstyle=three+,       
date=short,                
url=false,
doi=false,
eprint=false,
isbn=false
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % Activate Hyperlinks but do not show them.
\usepackage[german]{cleveref}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\title{example1}


\author{Simon Beyer}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

    \vspace*{2cm} 

 \begin{center} \large 


    {\huge example}

  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{example1}

\section{example2}
\section{example3}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things causing errors:

1. In the `center` environment you have an opening brace (`{`) without a closing brace. As it stands, you can just remove that brace.
2. `titlesec` is apparently not compatible with the KOMA-classes. I don't know if there is a way to use both, but the simplest solutions is either

   1. Remove `\usepackage[clearempty]{titlesec}`, or
   2. Use `book` instead of `scrbook`.

In addition, Overleaf doesn't seem to be able to deal with `biblatex`. Removing that package, and it compiles fine. This is a bit strange, considering that `biblatex` isn't used at all, and there are no errors in the `.log` file or the `.blg` file. I have no idea what's going on, at the moment. Even this minimal file makes Overleaf throw an error, even though there is no actual error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

I sent a message to Overleaf about this.

Comment: I tried both, but none of the ways resolves the error =(

Comment: @Rastaman For some reason `biblatex` causes Overleaf to choke. I have no idea why, it works fine when compiling locally, and the log from Overleaf also says that three pages of PDF output was written. At the moment, since you're not using `biblatex`, remove it. Later, when you add a bib-file and citations, see if works then.

Comment: after removing `biblatex` I get the following error message:

`./main.aux:4:
Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \abx@aux@sortscheme`

EDIT: after recompiling it works! thanks

Comment: @Rastaman Yes, the `\abx..` macro is defined by `biblatex`, and is written to the `.aux`  file, an auxiliary file that is read at the start of a compilation, and  rewritten during it. So the first time compiling, that macro is still there and unknown, since `biblatex` is gone, but the next time the `.aux` file has been recreated, and that macro is gone, so it works.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Right now what happens is that if biblatex is loaded but there is no `\cite` command, `latexmk` chokes with `biber test: failed to create output file`. (I've just got your message to Overleaf support and forwarded to our engineers)

Comment: There was a version of `titlesec` for about a week that behaved funny with the standard classes and failed completely with KOMA. By now everything is back to normal. Maybe Overleaf still has the buggy version.